# String representation of an HEX array

Tags: python

Please i need some help, i have a python script that parses serial data, the data is stored on a byte array.

the problem, i ave an array with the string representation of a datetime:

```
bytearray['\x01','\x35','\x40','\x02','\x21','\x016']
```

meaning that the array represents 01:35:40 02/21/2016

how can i parse this array into a datetime
i mean i can do this without a problem

```
datetime.strptime('01:35:40 02/21/16', %H:%M:S %m/%d/%y)
```

but i cant get the freaking str representation out of that hex array

please help!
thanks!

Comment: probably Python shows it as strings but it hex codes. You have numbers in array and you can do bit operations `data = bytearray('\x35') ; print( (data[0]>>4)&15, data[0]&15 )`

Comment: it is probably `BCD` [Binary-coded_decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) - four bits keeps one digit 0-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it looks like strings but `bytearray()` keeps numbers (bytes) and you see their hex codes.

It looks like `BCD` ([Binary-Coded Decimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)) and you can easily convert to integers using bit operations

```
import datetime

b = bytearray('\x01\x35\x40\x02\x21\x16')

# decode BCD numbers    
n = [(x>>4)*10 + (x&15) for x in b]

# add 2000 to year
n[5] += 2000

# create datetime object
#d = datetime.datetime(year=n[5], month=n[3], day=n[4], hour=n[0], minute=n[1], second=n[2])
d = datetime.datetime(n[5], n[3], n[4], n[0], n[1], n[2])

# print it
print(d.strftime('%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y'))
```

---

BTW: if you don't have Python `bytearray()` but normal list then you can use `ord()`

```
b = ['\x01', '\x35', '\x40', '\x02', '\x21', '\x16']
b = [ord(x) for x in b]

# decode BCD numbers    
n = [(x>>4)*10 + (x&15) for x in b]

# ...
```

Comment: Thanks furas, no more headaches parsing worng datatypes, i will use BCD on later implementations, no doubt that you learn new things every day!!